# How to run Eclipse without running JRE installation?

Tags: eclipse, java

I wish to run Eclipse for C++ on Vista but I absolutely do not want to run the JRE installation.  Is there any place where I can get a JRE in a zip that I can just dump in the Eclipse folder and have it work?

Comment: To clarify I don't want to install it because I don't want the browser add on.  I don't want registry entries.  I don't want it to modify path variables.  I also don't want the updater to ever run even once.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Download the JRE offline installer, right click on it, and have 7zip/winrar/whatever unzip it.

You'll get a folder with a fully funcional JRE, but no install required :)
You might want to read [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F) to run Eclipse with that JRE.

Comment: Odd. 7z unachieved it fine. Maybe winrar can't (I suposed it should, but didn't actually try)

Answer (score 21):

You can run Eclipse by copying the JRE into the `eclipse/jre` directory ([wiki documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F)).

The JRE is distributed with the [Java JDK](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp) (*/path/jdk1.6xxx/jre*). The JDK uses an installer, but you can just copy this directory from another machine, install and uninstall the JDK or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

The browser add on can be disabled per browser, you can copy and re-set your PATH variable and the JAVA_HOME variable, and you can disable the updater in the Java app in the Control Panel of Windows. Registry entries are generally harmless but not too hard to remove.

Also, you could just uninstall after you use it.

Comment: Sadly uninstalling the JRE does not remove the plugins.  This has worked for the most part but I'm still trying to figure out where it hid the IE plugin so that I might delete it.

Answer (score 1):

The IBM Development Kit for Eclipse is *exactly* what you ask for.  Eclipse with an JRE bundled in ready to use.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/eclipse/

(For the record it is an IBM JVM).

Registration is necessary (urgh).

Comment: If memory serves, the latest bundle available is Eclipse 3.0.0 with an IBM 1.5 (aka 5) JRE.

Comment: You appear to be correct.  I must have seen it with Eclipse 3.2 somewhere else then.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>No, it can not be done the way you described it. The JRE needs to be installed using the Installer. Why would you be so afraid of installing JRE on your machine? Without it, Eclipse won't work, as it is by itself a Java application and runs in a JVM.</strike>

**EDIT**, Pardon my ignorance. McDowell is right.

Comment: Plenty of apps redistribute the JRE. You can just copy it from machine to machine. See the jre/README.txt file in the JDK for more.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should take a look on [Apache Harmony](http://harmony.apache.org/). I beleive it could be just unpacked to the standalone directory. After that Eclipse could be launched with -vm PATH_TO_JVM option. (In theory)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just a note: Apache Harmony was officially retired in November 2011, so it's probably no longer a good idea to use it.