# Windows 8 - Running Eclipse (Java VM not found)

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-8, java

I just downloaded the Android Developer Tools Bundle. I started following the setup instructions and gotten as far as extracting the files to new location ("Development") as it says. I tried running the Eclipse app as instructed, yet a window popped up saying;

> A Java Runtime Environment (JRT) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following location:
>   C:.........\Development\adt-bundle-windows\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe
>   javaw.exe in your current PATH"

I tried compatibility trouble-shooter which can not detect a thing, whether it was the right action to take. I looked across stackoverflow and tried a few of the suggestions with no change. I looked at windows site and android site and nothing seems to make any difference, good or bad (well, I hope no bad).

I literally got this laptop 10 days ago and all programs are brand new, no updates or reinstalls etc.

I am running a Windows 8 with 64bit, which is what I selected at download of ADT Bundle.

---

I had downloaded the wrong java file. 
To fix I went to;

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7u7-downloads-1836413.html

and accepted terms then downloaded the appropriate file which I had to signup for registration;

Windows x64 90 MB    jdk-7u7-windows-x64.exe

It worked without changing any PATH.

Thank you..

Comment: Go here: http://java.com/en/ and click the free download button.

Comment: open the command prompt (cmd) and type `java -version`, if it says that the java command is not found, then proceed to install java, otherwise, update with the result

Comment: Since when did ADT work with java7??

Comment: this might be helpful(already existing forum page on StackOverflow):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129024/error-java-runtime-environment-jre-or-java-development-kit-must-be-available

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first download jdk(java development kit) and install it. the jdk includes the jre(java runtime environment).  You can also install the jre alone.

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded the wrong java. I will now give it another go.

Answer (score 3):

Thank It worked. Just add C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin in your PATH
Control Panel
1. System
2. Advance Setting
3. Advance
4. Environment Variables
5. System variable Group
6. look For PATH in the list
7. Edit 
8. Add path of your C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin jdk installation and save

Remember to separate value with ;

Answer (score 0):

You must download a JDK or JRE first from java.oracle.com, and add your installation folder in the PATH system avaiable.(Control Panel --System--Advance Settings --advance -- enviroment)

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded the wrong java. I will now give it another go.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the following page and download the executable on [java.com](http://www.java.com/en/download/windows_ie.jsp)
The executable installs the latest JAVA virtual machine.

NOTE: for Windows only
The installer knows your current version of windows.