# Eclipse for PHP installation error for Windows 8

Tags: php, windows, eclipse, java

Getting this error:

OS: WIndows 8 _ 64-Bit
Java JDK:  JDK 7 up 17

Getting below error after starting the eclipse.

> Eclipse for PHP Developers
>
> A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
>   must be available in order to run Eclipse for PHP Developers. No Java virtual machine
>   was found after searching the following locations:
>   C:\eclipse-php-3.0.2.v20120611144-Win32\eclipse-php\jre\bin\javaw.exe
>
> javaw.exe in your current PATH

Comment: This probably belongs on [Super User](http://superuser.com)

Comment: so here i can't get help regarding this ? should i go there and ask ??

Comment: @devilcrab Have you installed `JDK 7`?

Comment: @devilcrab I believe so. This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per [Windows 8 - Running Eclipse (Java VM not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577787/windows-8-running-eclipse-java-vm-not-found)

**Step 1:**

At first download jdk(java development kit) and install it. the jdk includes the jre(java runtime environment). You can also install the jre alone.

**Step 2:**

Just add `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin` in your `PATH`

goto Control Panel

```
1. System 
2. Advance Setting 
3. Advance 
4. Environment Variables 
5. System variable Group 
6. look For PATH in the list 
7. Edit 
8. Add path of your `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin` jdk installation and save
```

**Remember to separate value with ;**

**update 1:**

your New error (in comments) states you are using 32 bit version of java.

jdk is not 64bit.
Reinstall Java 7 for 64 bits.

**update 2:**

First,  Eclipse and JDK   have to be x64

Second, the -vm argument in eclipse.ini should point to the java executable. 
See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini for examples.

Comment: done above instructions, getting this error now-   ---------------------------
Eclipse for PHP Developers
---------------------------
Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\..\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll".

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: i downloaded java 7 64 bit ??   link:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u17-b02/jdk-7u17-windows-x64.exe?AuthParam=1365400102_a5ad20c024881257f9db4f0d6dac70ff

Comment: ahhh.. bit confused i downloaded same, and have reinstalled as well. see this-           

C:\Users\i_Code>java -version
java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: Download Java SE 7 JDK http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html Make sure that you choose the one is Java SE 7 – JDK

Comment: yea i download this -  

Windows x64 90.42 MB   jdk-7u17-windows-x64.exe

do we need to update eclipse config file for anything ? or Jdk 7 is not supported by Eclipse for PHP ??

Comment: can't find it helpful, as he can atleast work in eclipse.. and i can't.. :P What is the issue with my install then..

Comment: getting this error after updating config file for eclipse:

---------------------------
Eclipse for PHP Developers
---------------------------
Java was started but returned exit code=13
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\javaw.exe
-Xms128M
-Xmx512M
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar C:\eclipse-php-3.0.2.v20120611144-Win32\eclipse-php\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86
-showsplash
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: Well no issue, i have re-downloaded fresh Eclipse Helios and it simply works ! Thanks for your time and help :)

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
    Control Panel=>All Control Panel Items => System => open advanced system settings

    click on enviroment variable and check system variavle and check for 
     path,JAVA_HOME,ANT_HOME with correct path with 'C:DRIVE'
```