# javaw.exe cannot find path

Tags: java, virtual-machine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse will not open due to environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162121/eclipse-will-not-open-due-to-environment-variables)

I'm using eclipse IDE and I tried to run a project, but I'm getting error. It says the javaw.exe cannot be run.

I reinstalled Java, now I have JRE 7 and also I installed Jdk, but still no luck.

I opened cmd to run javaw.exe and it says:

C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin>javaw.exe
The system cannot find the file C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe

I think eclipse is installed correctly, but I have some trouble with Java. I reinstalled Java for 4 times. I don't know what to do. I can't forward with the tutorial that I'm trying to understand.

Comment: So....is `javaw.exe` in the specified directory? If not, then tell Eclipse where it can find the JDK that you've installed.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Make sure to download these from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html):

[image]

Also create `PATH` enviroment variable on you computer like this (if it doesn't exist already):

1. Right click on My Computer/Computer
2. Properties
3. Advanced system settings (or just Advanced)
4. Enviroment variables
5. If `PATH` variable doesn't exist among "User variables" click `New` (Variable name: PATH, Variable value : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin;` <-- please check out the right version, this may differ as Oracle keeps updating Java). `;` in the end enables assignment of multiple values to `PATH` variable.
6. Click OK! Done

[image]

To be sure that everything works, open CMD Prompt and type: `java -version` to check for Java version and `javac` to be sure that compiler responds.

[image]

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: A warning though: IF you already have a PATH variable then you MUST edit it and add ; at the end and then add your path. I made the misstake of just addin "another" PATH on Win 7 but it erased all the other user variable PATHs without asking.

Comment: Did you read "EDIT" part of my answer? :)

Comment: Yes but I think it's unclear because your (otherwise good) guide says we should press "New" and add a PATH variable. The EDIT part, IMHO, seem to suggest that we should still be pressing the "New" button but write C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin; (with a semicolon) . Doing that seems to erase all the old PATH data and therefore we must check before adding whether or not we already have a PATH variable. :)

Comment: @Aron I hope this latest update removed all misunderstandings.

Answer (score 8):

Just update your eclipse.ini file (you can find it in the root-directory of eclipse) by this:

```
-vm
path/javaw.exe
```

for example:

```
-vm 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/bin/javaw.exe
```