# Installing Android SDK and Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jvm

I am beginner level. I am trying to install the Android Bundle and Eclipse is giving me the error that it cannot find the JVM:

C:\Program Files\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe
javaw.exe in your current PATH"

I know there are some other threads discussing how to fix this including editing the eclipse.ini file, restarting, and making sure the architecture are the same for Android and Eclipse (x86, etc.). But I have spent over a day trying to figure this out and have been unsuccessful. I wanted to see if the community could assist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse will not open due to environment variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162121/eclipse-will-not-open-due-to-environment-variables) or [javaw.exe cannot find path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004851/javaw-exe-cannot-find-path)

Comment: I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling a few times and it hasn't seemed to work (or at least I am missing something further). Can you assist?

Comment: If you want an easy fix try Chuck's answer in the first link or the selected answer on the second link

Comment: I got this error: Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\..\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll"

Comment: I tried both methods in your suggestion. The latter one is yielding the error I posted above. The only improvement was Eclipse logo showed up before the error came up.

Comment: I tried dragging the jvm.dll file onto Eclipse, but that has been unsuccessful

Comment: And I finally got it to work! Dragging ftw.

Comment: idk how to upvote your comment but this was the answer that helped the most

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your correct answer is no java application likes it when you put a JVM in a subfolder with spaces..

@nd part of your problem..install the JDK not the JRE. in something like say C:\opt\jdk\jre\bin\javaw.exe will obviusly than be your pointer which you can put in the eclipse.ini file if need be after your install(you will not need to if you use the Oracle MSI installer for the jdk)