# Eclipse is not running due to eclipse.ini

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Windows 8 and I just restarted my laptop. WHen I tried to open Eclipse, I got the following error that can be seen right here [Eclipse will not open due to environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162121/eclipse-will-not-open-due-to-environment-variables) so I went to open my eclipse.ini and I have the following code but I have no idea what to do. Tried searching the web with no luck. Can anyone help?

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130521-0416
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: The thread you linked contains the two perfectly valid answers. Why didn't you use those?

Comment: Is it showing exactly the same error message saying `No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations` ? If so, there are already plenty of solution in the question you quoted.  If the error is different, tell us what it is

Comment: When I tried it, it didn't work for me.

Comment: @AdrianShum Same message and I tried some of the suggestion that was presented in the thread I provided but everytime I follow an advice, it keeps on bringing the same message.

Comment: So, is it showing the same error? I can't even see the `-vm` argument as suggested in the answer of the question you quoted

Comment: just wonder: is JDK's bin directory in your path?

Comment: Actually ZaoTaoBao's solution worked.

Comment: that's tell Adrian also works if you put you jdk's directory at your path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solution is  a little bit strange, but works for me..I have exactly your eclipe.ini..
and some time ago i find out the same error and i copy javaw.exe to the eclipse folder..i everything works prefectly. You can find javaw.exe at  you java path for example:
C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin