# PowerShell Add-Type : Cannot add type. already exist

Tags: c#, powershell, runtime-error

I'm using PowerShell script to run C# code directly in the script. I've run in to an error a particular error a few times. If I make any changes to the C# code in the PowerShell ISE and try to run it again I get the following error.

```
Add-Type : Cannot add type. The type name 'AlertsOnOff10.onOff' already exists.
At C:\Users\testUser\Desktop\test.ps1:80 char:1
+ Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (AlertsOnOff10.onOff:String) [Add-Type], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TYPE_ALREADY_EXISTS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

The way I have been resolving this error is by changing the namespace and the command to call the C# method `[AlertsOnOff10.onOff]::Main("off")`. I there a way I can prevent this error from happening without having to change namespace and method call?

Comment: I would suggest using VS and ex. a console application to develop and debug assemblies. PowerShell can use managed code, but it's not designed to be used as a replacement for VS(althought it's a great supplement)

Comment: Could this help? Of course if your type definition changes it won't help, but it might be a workaround if you are not planning to redefine the type: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552801/how-do-i-conditionally-add-a-class-with-add-type-typedefinition-if-it-isnt-add

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no way to remove a type from a PowerShell session once it has been added.

The (annoying) workaround I would suggest is to write your code in one ISE session, and execute it in a completely different session (separate console window or separate ISE if you want to be able to debug).

This only matters if you're changing `$Source` though (actively developing the type definition). If that's not the part that's changing, then ignore the errors, or if it's a terminating error use `-ErrorAction` to change it.

Comment: From my understanding, if I close my ISE session I won't run into this error. Is that correct?

Comment: While running ISE changes are not lost. So a variable `$wazzup` will persist after running a particular piece of code or script.

Comment: You can use `Remove-Variable` to get rid of a defiend variable, and you can clear other run-time objects. But this is not true of types.

Comment: This issue isn't a PowerShell limitation so much as it is a .NET limitation.  There's no supported way to remove assemblies once they have been loaded.

Answer (score 17):

For those who want to avoid the error or avoid loading the type if it's already been loaded use the following check:

```bsh
if ("TrustAllCertsPolicy" -as [type]) {} else {
        Add-Type "using System.Net;using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate, WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {return true;}}"
        [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
}
```

I post this because you get the error OP posted if you make even superficial (e.g. formatting) changes to the C# code.

Comment: I found a general solution. If you add "-namespace system" at the end of the add-type statement then you can always check the existence of the type via "[type]myTypeName". Even if the added type has no class. Without this the new type ends up as [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddType.AutoGeneratedTypes.myTypeName].

Answer (score 4):

You can execute it as a job:

```
$cmd = {    

    $code = @'
        using System;

        namespace MyCode
        {
            public class Helper
            {
                public static string FormatText(string message)
                {
                    return "Version 1: " + message;
                }
            }
        }
'@

    Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -PassThru | Out-Null

    Write-Output $( [MyCode.Helper]::FormatText("It Works!") )
}

$j = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $cmd

do 
{
    Receive-Job -Job $j

} while ( $j.State -eq "Running" )
```

Answer (score 3):

Adam Furmanek's  [blog](https://blog.adamfurmanek.pl/2016/03/19/executing-c-code-using-powershell-script/?fbclid=IwAR2THBg8sfOtnNrNoA-oQM3lPKaoXhOGdhq1D659CpA0xub2t15jyUgrqCc%20$id%20=%20get-random) has the simplest and best work around. This goes something like this below. If you want to see how to pass in parameters for that, you can see that https://samtran.me/2020/02/09/execute-c-code-with-parameters-using-powershell/

```
$id = get-random
$code = @"
using System;
namespace HelloWorld
{
    public class Program$id
    {
        public static void Main(){
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world again!");
        }
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp 
Invoke-Expression "[HelloWorld.Program$id]::Main()"
```

Comment: This will lead to your code unnecessarily recompiling every time with the old results piling up in memory.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is close Powershell and reopen it. Types you've added with Add-Type will be removed on closing, then run code again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
./YourScript.ps1
```

use this command

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "./YourScript.ps1"
```

Comment: Might you please [edit] your answer and explain a little how it resolves the problem in the question?  As discussed in [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/3744182), it's a lot more helpful to people if your answer also explain why its code works.  Thanks!