# Are DLLs loaded by reflection being cached?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, dll, reflection

I have an application that loads Type by reflection upon need since implementation may be changed by configuration.
here is a sample code:

```
var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("MyAssembly.MyClass, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1r46a5dfa04dase2"))as IMyClass
```

My Question here, is this Type being cached by default or it will be reloaded every time, and if not, How can I cache it to enhance performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once loaded an assembly can't be unloaded (unless you unload the full AppDomain that loaded it) (see for example [How to unload an assembly from the primary AppDomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123391/how-to-unload-an-assembly-from-the-primary-appdomain)). So there is the opposite problem of yours :-)

Now... You can surely speed up everything:

```
Type myType = Type.GetType("MyAssembly.MyClass, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1r46a5dfa04dase2");
```

This call will need to be executed every time. While the assembly won't be loaded, a search in the assembly will be done. You can cache `myType`.

```
var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(myType) as IMyClass;
```

This will search for a parameterless constructor for `myType` every time. You could speed up this by caching the constructor (`myConstructor`) you need:

```
ConstructorInfo myConstructor = myType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);

var myObject = myConstructor.Invoke(null) as IMyClass;
```

Now... Even using reflection is slow... you could create a dynamic method that invokes the constructor and cache it:

```
Func<IMyClass> myCreate = Expression.Lambda<Func<IMyClass>>(Expression.New(myConstructor)).Compile();

var myObject = myCreate();
```

So in the end you could cache only `myCreate` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike instances, single types and their containing assemblys are,once used, not unloaded (assuming only one AppDomain), so basically the answer is yes, there is a cache.

Also have a look here:
[Can you remove an Add-ed Type in PowerShell again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369662/can-you-remove-an-add-ed-type-in-powershell-again)