# Custom Class : Error TypeNotFound on my IDE but Working

Tags: powershell, inheritance

I'm trying to make a custom class with inheritance :

MyClass.ps1 :

```
class MyClass{

    hidden [Int] $Attribute1 
    hidden [Int] $Attribute2
    hidden [Int] $Attribute3

    MyClass() {
        $this.Attribute1 = 1
        $this.Attribute2 = 2
        $this.Attribute3 = 3
    }
}
```

MyDerivedClass.ps1

```
. ".\MyClass.ps1"

class MyDerivedClass : MyClass{

    MyDerivedClass() : Base() {}
}
```

Actually, the code works pretty well. However, in MyDerivedClass.ps1, MyClass was underlined in red with the following message: "Type [MyClass] was not found." This seems legitimate because it's a custom class.

Is there a way to remove or add an exception for all custom classes I use? I came across a method where I need to add MyClass to a .psm1 file and place the file in my PowerShell Module directory, but I'd prefer a solution that works on every computer that will use the script.

i'm using VS Code with Powershell Extension

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

#### First Problem and Solution:

You are unknowingly subjecting yourself to a known problem where "[PowerShell refuses to run scripts that contains class definitions that reference then-unavailable (not-yet-loaded) types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42839957/4190564)". This is a By-Design Behaviour where PowerShell, for security reasons, requires everything defining a class to be available at parse-time.

Weirdly, there are tricks to bypass this issue, so, wouldn't these trick introduce the same security risk?

Here is an example of one of these tricks:

```
. ".\MyClass.ps1"

$ClassText = @'
class MyDerivedClass : MyClass {
   MyDerivedClass() : Base() {}
}
'@

.( [scriptblock]::Create($ClassText) )

$ClassInstance = [MyDerivedClass]::new()
'Attribute1: {0}' -f $ClassInstance.Attribute1
'Attribute2: {0}' -f $ClassInstance.Attribute2
'Attribute3: {0}' -f $ClassInstance.Attribute3
```

#### Second Problem and Solution:

VSCode, by default, uses and reuses the same PowerShell terminal.  This means that when you first tried to run your code the class was loaded in that PowerShell terminal's memory and is available.  This can give you the illusion of everything is fine when it isn't.  Your code will not work with a newly opened instance of PowerShell.

The solution is to have VSCode reload PowerShell each time you execute your code.  You can configure VSCode to do this by following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72662104/4190564).

Answer (score 1):

The linting in VSCode can sometimes flag custom classes as errors, even though your code runs correctly.

Unfortunately, there isn’t a built-in way to add exceptions for custom classes in VS Code.

One workaround could be to adjust your settings in VS Code to ignore certain linting errors. You can do this by going to `File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Extensions, scroll down and find "Edit in settings.json"`. Restart VS Code after making these changes.