# How do i configure eclipse to make use of different version of JDK

Tags: eclipse

I have three project running on eclipse i want to use `JDK 1.4` for two project and `JDK 1.6` for third project how do i do that?

Comment: Also note there is two things here:  One being which JVM Eclipse uses to _run_ your program, and the other what JVM the Eclipse _compiler_ targets.

Comment: On a note unrelated to this question: **DO NOT** add "Thanks in advance" or similar clutter to posts. See this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need:

- first to declare the different JRE in your Eclipse: See "[Eclipse - no Java (JRE) / (JDK) … no virtual machine…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine/2843837#2843837)"
- then to add the right JRE in your project settings (see this [blog post for instance](http://www.upgradingdave.com/unsupported-major-minor-version-49-what-the-hell-does-that-mean))

[image]

> The default JRE is shown with a check mark and is used by new eclipse projects unless the project specifically overrides the value.
>   **So the next step is to check which JRE the current project is using**.
>
> - Right click the project and choose "properties".
> - Select "Java Build Path" and then click the tab labeled "Libraries". You should see an entry like "JRE System Library [version]".
>     To change the JRE version,
>
>   - highlight the entry and click "Remove".
>   - Then click "Add Library...". Choose "JRE System Library".
>       If you choose "Workspace Default", the project will use the JRe defined under "Windows -> Properties" as explained above.
>       You may also specify an alternate JRE located somewhere on your file system, or choose an embedded execution environment provided by Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

you can configure VM in [eclipse.ini](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) file.

Comment: Thanks @p27, I needed a 32 bits JDK to work with a custom 32-bits Eclipse, while my JAVA_HOME is set to a 64 bits.