# how to run a .jar 1.7 program with an older version java 1.6?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a code.jar running well in 1.7 version java, but when using another computer with linux with version 1.6 it is giving me an error, how can I run it in 1.6 version?

Comment: What's the error? It could very well be that you need the latest JDK to run it, period.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: tes : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
......
  
Could not find the main class: tes. Program will exit.

Comment: the error looks like this in the above comment

Comment: You need to create the .class files using a JDK 1.6 or use the `-target=1.6` option when compiling (but that won't help if you are using Java7 features)

Comment: Back in the old days of Java 1.4 you could use [Retroweaver](http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net) to run 1.5 code on a 1.4 JRE. Too bad it doesn't work anymore...

Comment: Do I need to uninstall the JDK 1.7 ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [cross-compilation options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-options) when invoking `javac`.

If only the `-target` option is specified as recommended in most other replies, the 1.7 SDK will issue a warning about `-bootclasspath`.  That option requires an `rt.jar` of the target JRE version (note **not** JDK).  It allows the compiler to check that the classes, methods and attributes of the code that reference core Java SE are actually present in the `rt.jar`.  This is very important to ensure compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

If the code is not compiled with an older Java compatibility flag, you won't be able to run it on 1.6.

Comment: what is the solution how can I change my code to be able to run it in an older version

Comment: First make sure the source code that ends up in code.jar is compilable with Java 1.6. Then, when you compile it with javac, use the -target 1.6 flag.

Answer (score 1):

Build the project using Java 6 in eclipse, you will need to download Java 1.6 JRE, then have eclipse point to 1.6 JRE, see: http://www.cleartoolkit.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=clearwiki:20.cleardatabuilder:01.setup:01.prerequisites

Now right click on your project -> Properties, click Java Compiler, uncheck "enable project specific settings", click "Configure Workspace Settings" , and select 1.6 as your compiler compliance level.

Do "the thing" to export your project again, the new jar should work.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can run higher version class with lower version.

Another approach may be while compiling set [target version](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) as 1.6.

Example:

```
javac yourFile.java -target 1.6
```

Comment: what is the commend ?
can I write javac -source 1.6 code.jar??

Comment: @user1475288: It is not source, it is target. Read the link provided in my answer.

Comment: but if my file is "yourfile.jar"
can I use
javac file.jar -target 1.6?

Comment: I don't think you can use this against jar.

Comment: I wrote the code using eclipse, then I made the export thing so that I can use it outside eclipse, but the version of java is 1.7 on my computer

Comment: If you are doing it in eclipse, set compiler version to 1.6 in eclipse. Everything taken care.

Comment: how i can set the compiler version to 1.6 in eclipse I'm new to eclipse :S

Comment: see the screenshot in this link, go to Java compiler and change it to 1.6 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638108/how-do-i-configure-eclipse-to-make-use-of-different-version-of-jdk?rq=1

Comment: I have a question not related to the subject, if I was opening a terminal session with a server and running a code on the server, then I close this session, does the code stops running?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution within Eclipse!

If you go to your project and right click to access the properties, there is a tab called Java Compiler. If you enable project specific properties and unclick the check box under JDK compliance, you can change the source compatibility and .class files compatibility to be 1.6.

This should fix your problem and the generated .jar file should work on both devices. I tested this by moving a file from 1.8 to 1.7 and testing on my Raspberry Pi that has OpenJDK 1.7 which worked great. I hope this helps.