# 'try catch' reconstruction from java 1.7 to java 1.6

Tags: java, try-catch

I am using a jar file from other person, but I need to add the source codes into my project and compile them when I import such packages. The issue is this jar file seems to generated by `java1.7` so it uses some `java1.7` fetures. But I am using `java1.6`. For this source codes:

```
public Properties getDefaults() {
    try (InputStream stream
            = getClass().getResourceAsStream(PROPERTY_FILE)) {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(stream);
        return properties;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    }
}
```

The eclipse gives such error hints:

```
Resource specification not allowed here for source level below 1.7
```

Then how could I rewrite such codes so that it can be handled by `java1.6`?

Comment: You have to go back to using the good ol' `finally` block.

Comment: can you be specific? Better to show some codes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17653793/1888799

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To re-write a try-with-resource statement compatible with Java 1.6, do the following:

- Declare the variable before the `try` block begins.
- Create the variable at the top of the `try` block.
- Add a `finally` block that will close the resource.

Example:

```
InputStream stream = null;
try
{
    stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(PROPERTY_FILE));
    // Rest of try block is the same
}
// catch block is the same
finally
{
    if (stream != null)
    {
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) { }
    }
}
```