# Piping between exceptions Java 7 feature

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, java-7

I am using pipes between exception. i.e

```
catch(InterruptedException|SQLException e)
```

Its showing compile time error and on mouse over it shows 
InterruptedException.SQLException cannot be resolved to a type
while on Java build path, I have added JRE7 as Java System Library and Java Compiler JDK Compliance is set to 1.7.

I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-0911

Can any one explain what would be the exact cause or what else I am missing.

Comment: did you import those exceptions?

Comment: Check whether the exceptions are really thrown from your code?

Comment: import for exceptions are added while exceptions are being thrown from the code. compiler is showing fix options 1 quick fix availabe, fix project setup

Comment: I think import statement is missing...

Comment: same code works fine if I removes | and defines two different catch clause

Comment: Have you set the project's language level to Java 7? Seems as though you're trying to compile it with a lower language level.

Comment: Java Compiler JDK Compliance Level is set to 1.7. where else i can set language level?

Answer (score 0):

To add on to what Mureinik suggests, Try setting the compiler compliance level in eclipse. 
This has been given in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638108/how-do-i-configure-eclipse-to-make-use-of-different-version-of-jdk).

Further, In the list of installed JREs add jre7 and remove any older versions of JRE that may be listed there.See image below:-

Ensure that your project build path has jre7 added to it.

[image: Installed JRE screenshot]