# No java virtual machine was found in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse - no Java (JRE) / (JDK) … no virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine)

I am trying to get Eclipse Indigo to re-Start on my computer - i have run it before with no problems but now i  getting error like this;

A java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: C:\eclipse\jre\javaw.exe javaw.exe in your current PATH

How can i rectify this problem?

Comment: That Answer is not useful sir

Comment: How can i rectify this problem

Comment: did you try the steps mentioned in that answer. How is that not helpful? Where did it fail? We will be able to help more if you give more details

Comment: @Nivas - yeah that question looks to be a) exact dupe b) answered in full. So why not helpful I don't understand.

Comment: I cannot open the Eclipse Ide,and also i chang the environmental variables Settings.please guide me clearly

Comment: guide me sir,i followed those instructions also But Am gettting Same error

Comment: @niva, did you try changing the values in eclipse.ini as mentioned in that answer? This does not need starting of the IDE

Answer (score 16):

You can specify JVM in eclipse.ini file at the Eclipse root folder, like this:

```
-vm
C:\java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\javaw.exe
```

This line must be placed before -vmargs options.

and for Linux

```
-vm
/..java address../bin/java
```

Comment: How can i  Specify this in root folder?At Which place -vmargs options is present?

Comment: @niva root folder is the folder where you installed Eclipse package, in your case this can be C:\eclipse, you can find eclipse.ini file inside this folder.

Comment: ya i tried Same Error is Occurred Again sir

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

- Look at your filesystem and make sure a java instance is installed in the mentioned path
- Open Eclipse and check the general preferences from Eclipse. Under 'Java' -> 'Installed JREs' must be a specified JDK configured.
- Next, open the general preferences 'Java' -> 'Build Path' -> 'classpath Variables' and look is there the jdk instance mentioned. If not, open dthe control settings from windows and add the variable 'Java_Home'.

Comment: i cannot open the eclipse IDE sir

Comment: have you checked the filesystem? Have you checked the enviroment variable 'JAVA_HOME'? What will happen if you open a dos prompt and executes 'Java -version' ?

Comment: C:\Users\elakkiya>java -version
java version "1.6.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Does it also work if you executes 'java -version' not in the install path else in a root folder like 'C:\'?