# Eclipse - No virtual machine found at location

Tags: eclipse

A Java Runtime Environment or Java Development Kit must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java Virtual Machine is found after searching the following location:

```
c:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_18/jre/bin
```

Comment: Hi KDE, welcome to stackoverflow! What exactly is your question?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077132/no-java-virtual-machine-was-found-in-eclipse/7077253#comment-8469553 and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine

Answer (score 0):

Point into your jdk bin folder: `c:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_18/bin` rather than the `jre/bin`

Answer (score 0):

Check the [PATH](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) environment variable from your system properties, you might have an entry c:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_18/jre/bin, is this path accessible or even actually there?

Open the eclipse.ini file on the root directory of eclipse. Add an entry as below

```
-vm
C:\Backups\jdk1.6.0_13\bin\javaw.exe
```

Note the line break between the -vm and the actual path. On other note, Eclipse uses its own built-in compiler and doesnt really need the jdk.