# Setting up eclipse on ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, java-7

I have a small problem with Eclipse on my Ubuntu machine. I installed JDK, set JAVA_HOME and PATH variables, all seems correct, but eclipse refuses to launch and throws an error:

> A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be
>   available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found
>   after searching the following locations: /opt/eclipse/jre/bin/java
>   java in your current PATH

have no clue what's the problem. help please.

note:

I am able to run java and javac in terminal.

Comment: You can force the java path of Eclipse in the ini file (root of your Eclipse directory), with the "vm" parameter. http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Comment: when you type "set" on the command line do you see JAVA_HOME?

Comment: @Benoit Courtine - Yep that works, but why isn't it working without forcing path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to set your JAVA_HOME env var something like:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/apps/java/jdk1.6.0_13
```

Check this [answer out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine)

Comment: So if you do env | grep JAVA_HOME it says the java path?

Comment: Do you get the expected output if you just run `java -version` or `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version` ?

Comment: You may need to add JAVA_HOME to your PATH env too

Comment: I get same version info on java -version and $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version

Answer (score 13):

If you get this error even though you already have JDK in your system-just follow this steps:

```
1)open eclipse.ini file with text editor.
2)copy your jdk path by using -vm command (vm and your path should not be in same line)
eg:
-vm        
/usr/lib/java/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/bin/java 
3)-vm should be placed before -vmargs in eclipse.ini file.
```

**99% works if you follow above simple steps**

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me:

```
ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a link at /usr/bin/java for the java binary (wherever you have placed it).

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/jre*/bin/java /usr/bin/java
```

Answer (score 1):

1. open your eclipse.ini file
2. add
   -vm
   usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.x_xx/jre/bin/java
   this must be placed before -vmarg
3. save the file
4. start your eclipse
   Happy Coding...

Answer (score 0):

it seems eclipse looks for java under /usr/bin directory, making a symbolic link of the java command in this dir would solve your problems, at least solve mine

Answer (score 0):

I have to run a number of jre and jdks on my machine and did not want to mess with the environment. I wanted to keep 1.6 for my environment but run eclipse under 1.7. I added the following line to my elcipse.ini file to specify the exact jvm to run eclipse:

```
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7_latest/bin/java
```

Obviously your path might be different. Note that above `jdk1.7_latest` is a symlink to the specific version of the latest Java 7 jdk.

Hope that helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of your jdk is not setup properly for current profile.
Before starting eclipse in your current profile. Run "java -version" command on your current profile where you are running eclipse. Surely it will ask to install jdk/jre even jdk already installed but on different profile.

Hence there is two way:
Solution 1. install jdk on current profile edit and add following lines 
vi /etc/profile 
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk-1.8
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

Solution 2: ~/.profiles
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk-1.8
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

Solution 3: I tried and working perfectly for me.
   1. gedit /home/../eclipse/eclipse.ini
   2. Add following line before -vmargs and any plugin or jar execution in eclipse.ini file

```
-startup
-vm        
/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_251/bin/java.exe
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.700.v20200207-2156.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.1100.v20190907-0426
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

This solution is perfectly working after explore from many stackoverflow suggestions and blogs.