# How do I configure JDK for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

As per the Dummies: Android Apps book, I downloaded JDK & SDK, but when I try using Eclipse, error message says that I need JDK or JRE.  How do I rectify this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you configure the java_home variables in windows. See this tutorial: http://wso2.org/project/wsas/java/1.1/docs/setting-java-home.html

Also make sure you point to java 6 SDK as java 7 is not supported for android development.

You can configure java sdk location in eclipse too, try: [Eclipse - no Java (JRE) / (JDK) ... no virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine)