# Create my own android app/ launcher

Tags: android, eclipse, launcher

First of all, what software would be the best to use and where can i download it?
Is there any program that lets me work more by visual rather than working with a bunch of code?

I looked at the information Android has for developers and i download Eclipse Classic. However i get this error when i try to run it.

" A java runtime environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: 
C:\users\administrator\desktop\eclipse…

If this turn out to be the best program to use....how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually Eclipse is the best tool to develop Android applications. And with the Android Development Tool (ADT) plugin for eclipse, you can create a simple interface graphically.

Use this tutorial to set up eclipse and ADT http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

The error you are facing is because you don't have the Java Development Kit (JDK) or it's not installed properly. Download it from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: I have now downloaded and installed Java Development Kit twice. but i continue to get this error. why? its like Eclipse is not looking in the right location for the JDK.... i dont really know...Does the JDK files need to be installed inside the eclipse folder?

Comment: Of course not. What you might need to do is tell Eclipse about the location of your JDK. This will help http://stackoverflow.com/q/2030434/569042

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the JDK.

See [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) and, in particular, step 1 and the link to download the [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)