# A Java Runtime Environment or Java development kit must be available in order to run eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse - no Java (JRE) / (JDK) … no virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine)

I installed the Android SDK and it mentioned that I should download eclipse as well, but when I download and try to run the eclipse.exe, I recieve a message stating "A Java Runtime Environment or Java development kit must be available in order to run eclipse....". I do have JDK, which is the only way the Android SDK would have been installed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this SO Post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine

Answer (score 6):

Set your computer's PATH (environmental variable) to the bin folder of your JDK. Here's how: 
Windows 7-Start->Control Panel->System and Security->System->Advanced system settings(panel on the left)->Advanced->Environmental Variables(bottom). Under System Variables find PATH. Select it and hit edit. Point it to the bin of the jdk. If that doesn't  work try adding a JAVA_HOME variable to the User variables ( hit new than enter JAVA_HOME for name and the value is the bin folder again). Hopefully that should do it. I feel your pain the same thing happened to me when I first started.

Comment: Now i get "Failed to load JNI library". Seems like it cannot find the jvm.dll. Do i have to download this as well?

Comment: Not sure. Didn't have this problem...

Comment: As long as you set JAVA_HOME, eclipse should be able to find your java installation.  Feel free to set  PATH to $JAVA_HOME/bin (on *nix) or %JAVA_HOME%/bin (on windows).

Comment: Do you have java installed? that was my problem...