# Google didnt help - A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Looks like a common issue, but facing issues inspite of searching around.

My environment: Win7 64.

Downloaded: [Java from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-jdk-6u29-downloads-523388.html) and Eclipse [from Here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download)
After installing Java & extracting eclipse, I try to run Eclipse from unzipped folder and get the error.  [image].

My background: C# .net / C++ - windows development. I would prefer to use C#. But not that adventurous to try going mono on android (unless recommended - unlikely). 
So trying to go Eclipse & Java the recommended way, although i have zero Java experience, so far.

Here is what I have tried.

1. Created env variables [as per this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621926/a-java-runtime-environment-or-java-development-kit-must-be-available-in-order-to). Didnt help.
   Java Install folder was - 'C:\glassfish3\jdk'
   Tried referencing both environment path with both these locations - 'C:\glassfish3\jdk\bin' and 'C:\glassfish3\jdk\jre\bin'. (I presume i should reference the latter - jre being the runtime environment?)
2. Modifying eclipse.ini - [from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162121/eclipse-will-not-open-due-to-environment-variables)
   (I dont think i am doing this right. I am not sure how to go about this. How to modify this file. Didnt try experiment much. Also, Do i need to remove the environment variables from previous step before attempting this?)

Could there be problem with the java i installed? There was some configuration items which popped up while installation. I just continued without configuring. (I thought it wes the additional items which i didnt need - glassfish)

Comment: i guess you need to install java SE only. jre is included with it. Java EE was not required.

Comment: This is java 7. I thought I needed 6 as per documentation of eclipse?

Comment: Will try uninstalling the previous bundle completely, and install this

Comment: thanks. That fixed it.
Not sure what i downloaded initially.

Comment: *"Not sure what i downloaded initially."* - That is a bit of a worry .....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you shouldn't have installed Java 6.  It is EOL'ed.  Install Java 7 instead.  And I recommend that you install a JDK not a JRE because that will give you the option of running Java development commands outside of Eclipse.

Next, when you install Java, it will ask you where you want to install it:

1. Make a note of that directory location.
2. When the Java install has completed, look in the "bin" subdirectory, and you should see the `javaw.exe` file.
3. Check the system `%PATH%` environment variable, and if necessary change it to add the Java installation's "bin" subdirectory.

(Note that this is basically what the Java release's installation instructions tell you to do ...)

---

If you don't want to do a reinstall, then use Windows search to find the `javaw.exe` file from your existing install, and add its parent directory to `%PATH%`.

Comment: Installing latest version helped me solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for the javaw.exe and add the location to your PATH.

Comment: that shud be a comment

Comment: Right, I cannot comment yet, though. I'll do it here.
Anyway, it seems strange to me the path it is looking for, H:\Android Device. Is it looking for Eclipse on Android?

Comment: actually it is trying to load from a folder located at 'H:\Android Dev\...'. Dev for development :)