# Developer Studio 2.1.0 and jdk 1.7

Tags: wso2

I am using the WSO2 Developer Studio version 2.1.0 which I downloaded in November. I want to use the jdk 1.7 to compile my projects.

I added this to the eclipse.ini file:
-vm C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_11/bin

When i attempt to set the Java Compiler preferences, the highest Compiler Compliance level is 1.6 - any idea how I can get eclipse to allow me to compile for 1.7?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the Developer Studio 2.1.0 preinstalled Eclipse distribution I will answer your question.

I do not believe Eclipse Helios support Java 1.7 by default. Hence you need to add the JDK 1.7 to your JDK list as explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine/2843837#2843837).

After that you should be able to use your Developer Studio with JDK 1.7.

However we have seen some issues running Eclipse Helios, Indigo and Juno with JDK 1.7 since Eclipse instances experienced some issues while installing new plugins with Eclipse P2 Updater due to some changes in JDK 1.7 implementations. Therefore I strongly recommend you to use JDK 1.6 instead of JDK 1.7 unless you are using Juno SR2.

/Harshana