# JDK/JRE 7 on mac os x 10.7.3 lion vbox guest, libjvm.dylib plug-in error

Tags: macos, java, virtualbox

I'm getting libjvm.dylib crash when launching swing/awt based java apps on my mac os x virtualbox guest. I'm not sure why is this happening. I was able to install the jdk on the guest, `java -version 
java version "1.7.0_15"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_15-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)`

Here's the log when I tried to open Java control panel.
http://pastebin.com/vHFWKeEk

`host specs: 
AMD Athlon(tm) 7750
3072MB RAM
ATI Radeon HD 5550`

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with JDK 7 Update 21. Any solution yet ?

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this error is that there is a compatibility issue preventing the Java 7 runtime from launching on OS X platforms lacking hardware-accelerated OpenGL support, including OS X VMware virtual machines running on Fusion and ESXi. The same applies for Virtualbox.

[Here you find a binary patch that solves the issue.](http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-22830) But attention, the provided patch only fixes the mentioned bug for the browser plugin! If you want to use the JRE/JDK for development purposes or to run SWT/AWT applications in your Mac OSX guest system, use the following script:

[VMware-Java7-patch.py](http://nicolas.baumgardt.ch/macosx/VMware-Java7-patch.py)

If you installed another version than the current JDK/JRE 7 Update 21, please edit the second last line of the Python script to point to your current JDK version (change jdk1.7.0_21.jdk to whatever version/directory you have currently installed on your system):

patchLibLwAwt("/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/lwawt/liblwawt.dylib")

Finally run the script by typing "sudo python ./VMware-Java7-patch.py" to your terminal/console.

This should do the trick and Java applications now should run without problems, without restarting your system. This patch works for VMWare and Virtualbox.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

If your error is related to JVM you have not installed JVM, or the path is missing for JVM,

File Structure of JDK and JRE [`link`](http://download.virtualbox.org/jdk6/archive/b104/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdkfiles.html)

this will state that if you do not have JVM installed you do not have the libjvm.dylib file installed.

I am still not sure that is the main reason, but that may be one of the reason..

Please check the path also, and read this [`old post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine)

this post states that 'You could register just a JRE within Eclipse because it is enough to run your program, but again a JVM will allow for more operations.'

So if swing/awt is advanced and dependent on jvm like in the older post in case of eclipse.

I am not Advance Java User, so not master in AWT/SWING..  :)

But one more thing I would like to add, it has option of memory overcommit, you must disable that as that causes problem, for crash [`link1`](http://opsmonkey.blogspot.in/2007/01/linux-memory-overcommit.html) read this blog for details. I found this details here [`link2`](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1557245&tstart=405)

I hope this will do :)

Answer (score 0):

I am running the same configuration and my VM was very slow. I have an Intel i7 processor which features the VT-x technology (Intel Virtualization Technology). AMD has a similiar feature called AMD-v. Be sure to activate that feature in your BIOS if available - it gives you notable performance boost.