# Downloading and using Android SDK

Tags: java, sdk, android-sdk-tools

I have the Java Android SDK package downloaded and I also have a jre downloaded and put in the same folder as eclipse, but when I go to run eclipse it is not starting and is giving me an error message saying that it cannot find a jre.
Wondering what is going on here.
Thanks,
Brett

Comment: Note you must have a JRE _installed_ in order for Eclipse to run.

Comment: I have the jre and eclipse installed

Comment: my problem is just the eclipse is refusing to start because it cant find my jre(in the same folder)

Comment: Make sure `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` are set.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394822/setting-up-eclipse-with-jre-path

Comment: thats the error im getting! i just need a step by step on how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a JRE or JDK on your `PATH` in order to run Eclipse.

If you are on Windows 7, go to Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Advanced > Environment Variables.  Find the `Path` system variable.  Edit it and append the location of your JRE's `bin` folder to the end of it.

Note that the JRE will be enough to run Eclipse, but to actually compile any code you will need a JDK.

Comment: would your receoommend the jdk over the jde?

Comment: Yes, you will need the JDK if you intend to write java code.

Answer (score 0):

you should download the android version of eclipse here http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
at this site you can also find the tutorials for setting it up as well

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html i used this page to download a pacakage inculding eclipse. which is that same page!!