# Why does Chrome Java updater installs a global 32bit JRE on a 64bit machine?

Tags: java, eclipse, 32bit-64bit

Recently I updated the JRE through the update process which chrome (Version 38.0.2125.104 m) offers ("your java is outdated and needs an update" or similar). The result was that my eclipse luna (64 bit) did not execute anymore. Looking closer to the background I detected: the chrome java updater (notabene started from an Oracle site) added C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath in front of the env var PATH. This folder contains three symbolic links to the newest java 8 JRE installation in (x86) program folder -> hence to a 32 bit java JRE.

Obviously Oracle replaced (with Java8) the old technique - having the java launchers in system32 (for 64bit applications) resp. SysWOW64 (for 32bit applications) - with this new approach. But: In these locations there still are the "old" java.exe/javaw.exe/javaws.exe, notably also actual versions (same file date as the new symlinks).

My questions are: 
a) what is the reason for installing a global 32bit JRE on a 64bit machine?
b) Is there a better approach to solve the problem than just deleting the new path entry?

Comment: I have no clue why chrome would give you the 32 bit version but it shouldn't really matter a whole lot considering 32 bit should run on a 64 bit architecture. As for the eclipse problem take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394822/setting-up-eclipse-with-jre-path

Comment: If you are running a 32 bit version of Chrome then a 32 bit version of Java will be downloaded. Click about Chrome to see if it contains a (64-bit).

Comment: @Frunk: You are right. Bit until now the problemless coexistence between the 32bit Chrome and the 64bit eclipse was granted. But when Oracle places now a 32bit JRE in front of the PATH this peace is broken. Is there another good reason why Oracle does it this way?