# Change incompatible JVM in eclipse when it can´t even open

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

Long story short I installed some plugins and extensions and now eclipse doesn't start.I was wondering how could i change the JVM , I already installed a the newer version required but i don't know how to change it.

[JVM not compatible popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5Rbc.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting up Eclipse with JRE Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394822/setting-up-eclipse-with-jre-path) or  [Eclipse will not open due to environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2162121/2711488)

Comment: It did! Thanks man.