# Eclipse 4.2 Juno doesn't find JRE

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I downloaded Eclipse Juno and I am trying to run it for the first time. System is Win 7 Home Premium and I also downloaded JDK.  I am getting the following error:

> A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be
>   available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found
>   after searching the following locations: C:\Program
>   Files\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe javaw.exe in your current PATH

The `javaw.exe` file it needs is in...
`C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe`

How do I fix this problem?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine

Comment: I downloaded jdk-7u21-windows-x64  It looks like it downloaded successfully.

Answer (score 4):

`" A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: C:\Program Files\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe javaw.exe in your current PATH "`

You need to install Java JDK: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

and then edit your path location:

Right-click on `computer`->`properties`->`advanced system settings`->`advanced`->`environment variables`:

[image]

Add `C:\Program Files\Java\<JDK version>\bin` to your PATH variable.

Also add `JAVA_HOME` as a system variable. I have my `JAVA_HOME` set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03`.

When you are done, start `cmd`, type `java`, and hit enter. If you get an error that it can not be found then java is not correctly installed.

Comment: should I put it in under System variables with "Variable Name" = javaw and then the path?

Comment: System variables, yes. There should already be a path variable there. You can append by adding a semi-colon and then "C:\Program Files\Java\<JDK version>\bin". You should also create a new variable: "JAVA_HOME". My JAVA_HOME is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03`

Comment: note: you'll have to restart every program that uses that variable, so if cmd is running, shut it down and restart it after making the variable change.

Comment: Jason Thanks, You are the bomb...  God bless you.  bye

Comment: hmmm nevermind. you may not have enough reputation. normally there is a check mark underneath the upvote/downvote

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have a Java environment installed in one of the locations Eclipse looks. For Eclipse you do *NOT* need the full JDK.

It is enough to install a Java Runtime Environment, e.g. from java.com.  This still allows you to develop against any JDK - this is just about the JVM that Eclipse needs for itself.