# Eclipse not running (even with JRE installed)

Tags: eclipse, java

I have JRE 6 installed (can't update due to admin restrictions), but all of a sudden Eclipse won't start up. It has worked in the past. Here's the error message I'm getting:

> A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations:
>   C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Desktop\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe
>   javaw.exe in your cuurent PATH

If this is due to some sort of admin restrictions (nothing seems to be different from before), is there a way I can use Eclipse in another way? Perhaps without the JRE?

EDIT: jre\bin\javaw.exe does not exist. Why is it looking for it there?

Comment: Duplicate/related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2030988

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the `-vm` entry in the `eclipse.ini` configuration file. The format is

```
-vm /path/to/jre/bin/javaw.exe
```

If this entry does not exist, then Eclipse is using the a `JRE` on the current system's `PATH`

Change/add the `-vm` entry to point to a new existing `JRE`.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your environment settings. Your JAVA_HOME should point to Java Folder and Path should have JAVA_HOME/bin;

Comment: Note that [Eclipse **DOES NOT** consult the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F), only `PATH`. The `JAVA_HOME` is not required at all.

Comment: That's why I mentioned to set the Path as well. It is always better to ensure that your JAVA_HOME is set.

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` is nowhere used by Java itself. It's only sporadically used by a few 3rd party programs such as Tomcat. But Eclipse definitely not.