# JAVA - path issue (works in eclipse, not in cmd)

Tags: java

Why the following iniciation works in eclipse:

```
private static MaxentTagger maxentTagger = new MaxentTagger("c:\\DP\\lemma\\models\\english-left3words-distsim.tagger");
```

but in command line it throws:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at dp.beans.MySearch.<init>(MySearch.java:122)
        at dp.runable.Main.main(Main.java:25)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader.findResource(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(Unknown Source)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.findStreamInClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:370)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:399)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:646)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:284)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:248)
        at dp.data.Settings.<clinit>(Settings.java:80)
        ... 7 more
```

`Settings.java:80` corresponding with `MaxentTagger` iniciation..

Is there a different way to declare windows path, which works in both, eclipse and cmd?

**update** (the `findStreamInClasspathOrFileSystem` method):

```
private static InputStream  [More ...] findStreamInClasspathOrFileSystem(String name) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
  String path = null;
  if (name.startsWith("/")) {
    path = name.substring(1);
  }

  // - even though this may look like a regular file, it may be a path inside a jar in the CLASSPATH
  // - check for this first. This takes precedence over the file system.
  InputStream is = null;
  if (path != null) {
    is = IOUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);

    // windows File.separator is \, but getting resources only works with /
    if (is == null) {
      is = IOUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path.replaceAll("\\\\", "/"));
    }
  }

  // if not found in the CLASSPATH, load from the file system
  if (is == null) is = new FileInputStream(name);
  return is;
}
```

**update:** no matter if i change the path to:

```
  "c:/DP/lemma/models/english-left3words-distsim.tagger");
  "c:\\\\DP\\\\lemma\\\\models\\\\english-left3words-distsim.tagger");
```

its behaviour is still the same (works in eclipce, not in cmd)

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine

Comment: It is impossible to know without complete code but this line seems the first suspect: `IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem`. It does not correctly recognize this is a file and tries to load it from classpath which fails

Comment: And i forgot to tell you, it's running in Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to load a resource from the classath, using the ClassLoader. The path should take the following form:

```
com/yourcompany/yourapp/english-left3words-distsim.tagger
```

where `com.yourcompany.yourapp` is the package where the file resides.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29

EDIT:

The code of `IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem()` passes two badly formatted paths (`c:\...` and `c:/...`) to ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(), and expects this method to simply return null instead of throwing an exception, which is wrong. I would simply decide where I want to load the resource rom: either the classpath (and thus use `ClassLosader.getResourceAsStream()`) or the file system (and thus use `new FileInputStream()`).

Comment: Thank you. But I think I don't understand you well. Why it looks to claspath, if the absolute path is specified? Couldn't be the problem in the sysntax of path string?

Comment: Probably because edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem() is buggy. I would decide where you really want to load the resource, and directly get it from there: either the classpath, or the file system.

Comment: This is one reason of why it's better to accept an InputStream instead of a String in a constructor. Classic mistake..

Comment: Aha, thank you! I've undestood it that. What I don't understand is, why it works in eclipse :-| So I have to, place it to system path..