# Eclipse : Jre not found and PATH

Tags: java, eclipse

![][1]
Eclipse couldn't be launched beccaus of JRE or PATH i really need help

I tried to reinstall JDK but nothing changed

Comment: On which operating system ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse - no Java (JRE) / (JDK) ... no virtual machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine)

Comment: Go to http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp and follow instructions until Java is reported installed.  Eclipse should now start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before Installing Eclipse set PATH for your JDk in your computer.

1. Right click on computer GOTO properties and select Advanced Settings
2. One pop-up will appear select Environment variables and select new in user variables
3. Give variable name=`PATH` and Value=`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin;`.

Variable value where you installed your JDK select that path and Click OK, OK, Ok

Now yo can install your IDE

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your system environment variable `JAVA_HOME` has been set.

On windows, set the variable in system properties to some path like:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk64bit_1.6.0_30

Or, on linux, edit `/etc/profile`, add the path below:

> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/share/jdk1.6.0_30

Then eclipse will find JDK to launch.