# ADT Bundle can't find Java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, installation

When I open adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030 and click on the Eclipse.exe application to install it I get the message; A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java Virtual Machine was found after searching the following locations: C:\users\username\desktop\development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe
javaw.exe is your current PATH.

I do have JDK, and JRE on this computer, I need them to view the emulator for my job. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Java with the same results. What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Thank you to all of you who tried to help. I finally got it. Used System Restore to restore my settings to yesterday, then changed the path in Windows again. Worked this time. Thank you again, and I really appreciate your input. Believe it or not, I did learn a thing or two from this.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to put Java in your classpath, so Eclipse knows where it can find Java. See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html for info on how to do this.

Comment: I tried your fix. Followed the instructions in the tutorial, and am still getting the same message.

Comment: If you open a command prompt (Windows-key + R -> type `cmd`) and type java, what is the output?

Comment: 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Currently have path under Environment variables set at "c:\Program Files (x86)\java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe"

Answer (score 0):

install 32 bit version of jdk from oracle website

Comment: The 32 bit is required by my companies mainframe emulator. I have tried both 32 and 64 bit versions of the SDK with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

put the path of your java bin directory under Environment variables.
System->Advanced System Settings->Environment Variables->path

Open command prompt. use java and javac commands to know if you have successfully installed java and compiler.

if it doesn't help, this question has a lot of helpful answers
[Eclipse - no Java (JRE) / (JDK) ... no virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine?rq=1)

Comment: I did that, and I still get the same error message. I even went as far as to uninstall Java and reinstall it in the eclipse folder specified in the path it is looking for, still didn't work.

Comment: Currently have path under Environment variables set at "c:\Program Files (x86)\java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe"

Comment: try setting Path for both jdk and jre. use ; to separate paths. and try visiting the link I've given. There's already a great discussion on the same problem. so i believe that will help you.

Comment: Thank you VipulKumar. What I did was reset my system settings with System Restore, then re-entered the path, again. seems to have taken it this time. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Well that must've been pretty messy. sorry you had to perform a SystemRestore. Java can be really a headache sometimes :) anyways, glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

From what you said:
"'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Your java may not have been installed correctly, or, it was installed, but you did not set path to it correctly. It is not a problem with ADT, any of your programs that need Java will not be able to find it.