# Android SDK manager not working, unable to create AVD

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I am new to android and trying to setup the environment using ADT bundle.
But when I run android sdk manager from eclipse, I see the following error in console

[SDK Manager] '"C:\Users\ADT-BU~1\sdk\tools\lib\find_java.exe" -s' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.

I already have Java installed on my system. Please let me know how can i fix this.
Also, I have java already included in my path.

Comment: Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180954/adt-bundle-cant-find-java

Comment: I have already seen this.. my java is already added to path   JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01
PATH: <path>;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the official instructions to install properly. I recommend you to try this from the beginning. It will not take so much time. Your error probably caused by skipping a part of the installation because unfortunately it is still a challenging process :(

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=adt

Comment: SDK MANAGER is not getting opened, i tried following the steps all again but still not working. :(

Comment: Finally I can offer you to look at this post and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199811/android-sdk-manager-wont-open

I hope you could fix it.