# My Eclipse wont run because a JRE environment is needed, and it cant find one

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime-error

My eclipse has always worked for about a year, until recently i updated my Java, and when i tried using it this error popped: A java runtime Enviorment must be available in order to run eclipse.

Also i use intellij and that works perfectly fine.

I am using windows 7 64bit java version 7 and latest eclipse.

Comment: A lot of information is needed what java version, eclipse version and bit for both. Even the error why eclipse won't open.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine

Comment: Have you change JDK and JRE HOME and respective PATH in environment variable to one which you recently installed?

Comment: I confirm with Aeshang. Please check the version of your eclipse. Maybe it is a 32bit version, then you also need a 32bit java version instead of 64bit. Or update your eclipse to a 64bit version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the contents of the file `eclipse.ini`. If probably contains a line `-vm`. Make sure the next line (which must contain the absolute path to the Java version to use) is correct.

If there isn't a `-vm` line, then add one:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\...\java.exe
```

Rules: Spaces are okay, quotes aren't. The `-vm` must be on one line and the absolute path to `java.exe` in the next.

Note: There is also `-vmargs` which does something different.

Comment: I only have this: -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
Thats all it dislpay, on one line.

Comment: @Stratmoss: See my edits how to configure Eclipse to use a specific Java VM.

Comment: I dont have -vm though?

Comment: @Stratmoss: "If there isn't a -vm line, then add one"?

Answer (score -1):

Goto to eclipse folder and check in `eclipse.ini` which version is set over there. If it does not match with your JRE version change it by using this one

```
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
```

Comment: I only have this: -startup plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar --launcher.library plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product --launcher.defaultAction openFile --launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256M -showsplash org.eclipse.platform --launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256m --launcher.defaultAction openFile --launcher.appendVmargs -vmargs -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7 -Xms40m -Xmx512m Thats all it dislpay, on one line. –

Answer (score -2):

Go to Eclipse>Preferrence>Java>Installed JREs. Check which JRE it is pointing to.

Comment: I cant open eclipse, thats the problem