# MATLAB IDE setup : Eclipse IDE error : JVM

Tags: java, eclipse, matlab, jvm

I have installed eclipse 3.4 and it's working. I tried to setup IDE with 'eclipseidesetup'. when I give the eclipse path and press OK it says:

`You are trying to set up the 64-bit Eclipse IDE with the 32-bit Java Virtual Machine (JVM). Eclipse IDE will not open due to this mismatch. Please make sure your Eclipse IDE is compatible with your JVM.`

which is absolutely wrong because my eclipse is working and my JVM is 64-bit because of my system. what's making this happen?

I've read this matlab help articles and none helped:

- Tested Software Versions
- Installing Third-Party Software for Eclipse
- Configuring Your MathWorks Software to Work with Eclipse
- Troubleshooting with Eclipse IDE

OS: Linux mint - kernel 3.14.17 - 64bit
MATLAB R2014a

Comment: May be you have multiple JVMs installed and the one eclipse points is the one 32-bit version to handle this see that question :http://stackoverflow.com/q/2030434/1460591

Comment: I just have one JAVA installed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should [update your IDE to version 4.4](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-standard-44/lunar), then you will probably need to install [the x64 version of the JVM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) to make it run properly.

Comment: In MATLAB: 'version -java' returns : Java 1.7.0_11-b21 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode. I already have Eclipse 4.2 and it's working. I installed 3.4 because it's recommended by MATLAB.