# when opening eclipse gives “Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'”

Tags: java, android

opening an eclipse like this error came what i do so please help me any one.
-> “Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'”
please help me

Answer (score 0):

It Might be a slightly different cause,the second issue occurs for me in scala 2.9.0.1 on Win7 (x64), though scala-2.9.1.final has already resolved this issue mentioned here:

```
     \Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\java.exe was unexpected at this time.
        My %JAVA_HOME% set to a path like this: c:\program files(x86)\Java\jdk...

        Note the space and the parentheses.

        If you change line 24 in %SCALA_HOME%\bin\scala.bat from:

        if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" set _JAVACMD=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe
        to

        if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" set "_JAVACMD=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"


    It works fine. Note the quotes around the set command parameters, this will properly enclose any spaces and 'special' characters (eg: spaces and parentheses) in the variable's value.
```

Comment: A java Runtime Environment (jre) or java development kit(jdk) must be available in order to run eclipse . no java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: D:\---------------------------
Eclipse
---------------------------
A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:
D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe

Comment: please use the link      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine

Comment: Didn't work for me, gave me Error: opening registry key 'Software\Javasoft\Java Runtime Environment'. I had to copy the whole jre7 (in my case) folder into the Eclipse directory, and rename it jre. after doing this error came that is error: opening registry key 'software\javasoft\java runtime environment.