# No virtual machine was found error: Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When i tried to run eclipse, i am getting the following error:
"No virtual Machine was found after searching the following locations:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\server\jvm.dll"

Comment: I googled the error and found something. Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/ddg#2843837)?

Comment: From a command line, try the command "java -version" . Just to check JDK is correctly installed.

Comment: You also need to check that it is a 64 bit JVM if you are running Eclipse 64 bit, and a 32bit JVM if you are running Eclipse 32 bit.  If the you don't have a >>matching<< JVM, Eclipse will say the above.

Comment: i have tried java -version command. it is showing the version.

Answer (score 1):

Check if in the file `eclipse.ini` in the base directory of Eclipse there is a line for define the JDK to use to launch Eclipse. An example of parameter definition is:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/javaw.exe
```

You have to check the following things:

- The path exist and it is a JDK, not an JRE.
- Eclipse version must same of JDK: an 64bit Eclipse need an 64bit JDK, an 32bit Eclipse need a 32bit JDK.

Hope it helps.

Comment: yeah, i got it. i have installed 32 bit Eclipse for 64bit JDK