# Error popping up while running Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, windows, scala, windows-8, 64-bit

i have downloaded scala-SDK-4.4.1-vfinal-2.11-win32.win32.x86_64 , also installed JDK 7 on my windows 8 64 bit laptop ,but i have a issue while running the eclipse as shown below, some one please help to resolve my issue, it would be really appreciated. I have browsed internet to get resolution for this ,none helped to resolve the issue, please help what i am missing here

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i have installed required software to run eclipse , but still i m facing issue. please assit me what need to be done .

Comment: Your PATH environment variable is probably not pointing to the correct path where your JRE is installed. In the link that I posted, you have information about how to edit the PATH variable in Windows. The correct path of your JRE probably ends with ...../jre/bin (or something similar). What is happening is that Eclipse is trying to start and, to do that, it needs Java, which is installed in your system but Eclipse is not finding it.

Comment: this is me jre installed path C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_71\bin , i have editted eclipse.ini and added C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\bin , still im getting the same error i have attached the screen shot above.

Comment: No, @MarioCervera, do NOT use PATH to specify to Eclipse where the JVM is. `eclipse.ini` is the proper way to go.

Comment: Hi E-riz/Mario , could any one tell me to sort out this issue.

Comment: If it's under `Program Files (x86)`, it's 32-bit. Your 64-bit Scala requires a 64-bit Java Runtime.

Comment: yeah , its great help, i ahve downloaded 32 bit eclipse and now i m able to run eclipse, thanks a lot for the promt help.

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of misinformation about this out there, including SO answers. The right way to specify to Eclipse what JVM you want it to run in is via [eclipse.ini](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini). Other options are less than ideal and/or susceptible to system changes breaking them.

Pay careful attention to the format of the ini file and the exact path it requires; it is very picky.

Comment: what are the check to be made to run eclipse on my system, please assit.