# version 1.7 of the jvm is not suitable for this product. version 1.8 greater is required for eclipse nano in window

Tags: eclipse, jvm, window, version, eclipse-neon

I am trying to launch Eclipse Nano in Windows 7, but getting the error:

```
Version 1.7 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. version 1.8 greater is required for Eclipse Nano in Windows
```

I already have Java 8 installed on the system

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sudo /usr/sbin/update-alternatives --config java
```

and select the jvm 1.8

Comment: This gives the message `There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Nothing to configure.`

Comment: +1. On my Ubuntu 18.04 (upgraded from 14.04) the path was different:

`$ which update-alternatives 
/usr/bin/update-alternatives`

Answer (score 10):

Simply download 1.8 JDK from [Java SE Development Kit 8 Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) install it, then copy the jre folder & paste it in:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\EclipseNeon\"
```

Then rename the folder to "jre", start the eclipse again it should work.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue (Windows 10). You need to set the **"JAVA_HOME"** system environment variable to point to JDK 8 folder and edit the **"Path"** system environment variable to have a new path to JRE 8's **bin** folder, this should be at the top of the list.

Comment: Also, remove any directories from Path that point to old JDK versions.

Answer (score 2):

I too got the same error while installing

Possible reason for the error - The eclipse version, you are installing and the Java version should be of same bit, i.e. either 32 bit or 64 bit

Solution: I have downloaded both the java for 64 bit and 32 bit and installed, now my problem is gone.

Please let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

When you download the latest eclipse, and extract it, you can find the folder named eclipse-installer with eclipse-inst file inside it. Instead of double-clicking it to start installation, just navigate to the folder in terminal and run `./eclipse-inst` command. It does the entire installation for you. It worked for me and hope who also got the same problem(version 1.7 of the jvm is not suitable for this product. version 1.8 greater is required) gets solved. :)

Comment: I installed eclipse using `apt-get` on Unbuntu.  Where is the installer?

Comment: I am amused.  When I found the directory and run the installer, it says `Version 1.7.0_181 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 1.8 or greater is required.`

Answer (score 2):

On a Windows system I had the same problem.

Although I had only Java 1.8 installed, I found that I also had a 1.7 upgrade file installed too (which didn't get uninstalled automatically when I installed 1.8).

Uninstalling this upgrade file allowed me to install Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I had a different solution to this problem.
Though I set the `JAVA_HOME` to 1.8 (Both through CMD and environment variables), the error was persisting.

So I opened CMD prompt, typed:

```
java - version
```

to find out 1.7 was the version my system was set to. Until then I had no clue from where it was fetching this version.

And then I changed it to 1.8 using this command:

```
set path=C:\.....eclipse\jdk1.8.0_141-b15\bin
```

AND IT WORKED!

Recheck if it is set to 1.8 with the same command:

```
java -version
```

You should be good to go now!

Answer (score 2):

if it's a 64-bit Eclipse. You'll need to explicitly download and install the 64-bit Java 8 or later.

download it from here 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: Thank you! The eclipse installer provided a bad link.

Comment: There are many options to choose from there.  How do I know which one is the right one?

Answer (score 2):

tips for windows users

> Version 1.7 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. version 1.8
>   greater is required

- user get above error message because they had multiple jdk version or they do not have latest version of jdk installed , even if you install latest version of jdk and you if you have not removed old version of jdk like 1.7 you will get the above error message , so better to get rid of old version of jdk and jre etc.

-> ignore this step if you have insallted latest version of jdk already 
download 32 or 64 bit latest jdk from : https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

-> go to C:\Program Files\Java  and look for old version of jdk , let say if you have 1.7 versions of jdk delete them so that you are left only with latest version , you can remove old versions of jre too here just by deleting.
-> next run eclipse you will not get v1.7 message

Answer (score 1):

Find the JVM

If a JVM is installed in the eclipse/jre directory, Eclipse will use it; otherwise the launcher will consult the eclipse.ini file and the system path variable. Eclipse DOES NOT consult the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

To explicitly specify a JVM of your choice, you can use the -vm command line argument:

eclipse -vm c:\jre\bin\javaw.exe             ''start Java by executing the specified java executable
eclipse -vm c:\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll         ''start Java by loading the jvm in the eclipse process

Answer (score 1):

Go to Eclipse directory, find and open eclipse.ini configuration file then modify below parameter to your desired version, it will work.

`-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8`

It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

1. Eclipse will consider the version that is mentioned in eclipse.ini file, this error 
   means that your installed java version (in environment variable) and the mentioned java 
   version in eclipse.ini file is not matching.
2. You may just change the java version there (it will be in eclipse-installation-dir).
3. Change the property as below:- 
   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=

Comment: Or a better way instead of this- if you have multiple JDK and JRE installed, you would have to remove the older ones. Eclipse will go through Java folder and use the first 1 it finds. Even if you have the latest one, it will pick the one at the top and start using it. This is what I did and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Updating below line in eclipse.ini worked for me
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

Check this question here as it's similar and has some good pointers [Eclipse - no Java (JRE) / (JDK) ... no virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine)

Also, get the latest JRE and JDK from Oracle vs from java.com http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: The OP would not get this message if no Java was installed. It looks like either just Java 7 or both Java 7 and Java 8 are installed.

Answer (score 0):

Today I meet the same question. I download the file that named "eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz". When I open the eclipse, it shows "Version 1.7.0_121 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 1.8".Then execute

```
cd /usr/bin/
sudo ln -s /Your_JAVA_PATH /usr/bin/java
```

Then you can install eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure java and eclipse versions are same(32bit or 64bit)
- Try running eclipse-installer as administrator(this worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to skip this step just simply change Required Version number, ex:
open with any text editor instalation path/AptanaStudio3.ini 
and change
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 to -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7

This is just for skipping this step.

Answer (score 0):

I had both 1.7 and 1.8 in path and 1.7 was on top and 1.8 below in Pah, so i moved 1.7 below 1.8, thats it it worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Oracle's website and download the newest version of Java JDK. (https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html)
2. Install the program on your computer.
3. Remove all old environment variables related to Oracle and Java.
4. Set the environment variables related to the new installation all the way to the bin folder. (include the bin folder in the environment variables section)