# Java database path not found

Tags: java, database, eclipse, path, classpath

I'm attempting to change the file path of eclipse java neon to access a database I need for my programming class and I cant figure out how to do it for windows 10 (the book only instructs us on on how to do it in window 8 and 7).

I'll give you the short version and just say that the book tells me to either edit the current `classpath` to look something like .;`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\db\lib\derby.jar` or to make a new one that looks like that.

The problem is when I changed it to look like that **it kept giving me a path error and I just need to fixed that error.** My version of `Java` is `jre1.8.0_111` and the `database` I am supposed to be making is called `CoffeeDB` (though I don't think you need that info).

The end game of this is to be able to connect to databases so I can do my homework of creating and changing them.

If you need more information to help I am more than willing to give it, I'm just not sure as to what more you would need.

Comment: I don't use Eclipse but can't you just copy derby.jar into your particular project folder (directory) and then add the library to your project through the project property settings?

Comment: What is the error? Are you getting `ClassNotFoundException` ? Also, list how exactly do you run the program? Windows Command line, Eclipse, Unix shell ?

Comment: A Java runtime environment (jre) or java development kit (jdk) must be available in order to run eclipse. No java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: C:\Users\Frank\eclipse\java-neon\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe javaw.exe in your current PATH       that is the error that I am getting.

Comment: I can also link the program that we are supposed to run once we have it connected. Its a bit long but it gives a few error messages in the program that may be of use to people trying to help, should I link it?

Answer (score 0):

> Specifying the classpath for your pc

See these IBM [article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-classpath-windows/index.html?S_TACT=105AGX99&amp;S_CMP=CP) and Oracle [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) about classpath management.

> Specifying the classpath for eclipse

Eclipse usually sync the class path with the system. But just to be sure -

Step 1:
Right click on your current project -> Build Path -> configure built path

Step 2:
On left side tab; select Java Built Path

Step 3:
On right side tab; select Add Library

Step 4:
Select JRE System Library.
Select Environment, Installed JRE(jdk 1.8) -> Finish -> Apply -> OK.

> Related Question (problem related to installation of JDK, JRE)

Maybe you find something beneficial here

[Eclipse - no Java (JRE) / (JDK) ... no virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2030434/6721308)