# No java Virtual Machine was found to run eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

i am having difficults to repair my eclipse due this problem:
"A JRE or JDK must be available in order to run eclipse. No virtual machine
was found"

i looked the path that contains the \bin file to that is missing and realized that my jdk and jre has different versions (jdk 1.8.0_102 jre 1.8.0_112)
could be this the problem? if yes, how can i update them both?

i search in the oracle website but didn't found an older version of jre

how could be the better way to fiz this problem,

tks

Comment: jdk 1.8.0_102 jre 1.8.0_102  looks like they are the same version

Comment: Did you specify the `-vm` option in the `eclipse.ini` file? If so, verify it is correct. If not, can you run `java -version` in a comment-line? If not, that's why.

Comment: Error: CPU not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Solution regarding no java (no virtual machine)

[Eclipse - no Java (JRE) / (JDK) ... no virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2030434/6721308)

> Solution regarding class path in eclipse

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41118900/6721308