# No Java VM found for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have a similar problem to [Eclipse - no Java (JRE) / (JDK) ... no virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine), but I do have matching JRE and Eclipse, they are both x64. I've used to run Eclipse w/o any problems for a long time, now I can't even get it to start. I don't want to stick to copying JRE for extended periods of time, for understandable reasons, nor hard-wire the path in my `eclipse.ini`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the latter, I've immediately found something not quite right. This portion of the file has been causing the error:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_112/bin
```

Eclipse expects the *full path* to the Java VM here, but somehow, there is no file name. Of note that I never ever touched the file beforehand, but somehow it got updated with correct path to just recently installed JRE v1.8 vs previously installed v1.7. A mysterious force surely is to blame. Deleting the lines fixed the error; still, how did they appear and appeared *updated* w/o my intervention needs further investigation.

Comment: Actually the path to the jre bin directory is a perfectly acceptable value for the -vm argument. See the description of -vm in the [help](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html)