# How to get Scala and Java to work with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, scala, visual-studio, ide

I am trying to use Java with VSCode, but when I run my Java code, I am getting

```
Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Also, does anyone know how to get Scala on VSCode? I can't seem to find much information on it.

Comment: Hi, try searching for your question before posting it - There is a similar question on eclipse
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine

Comment: Scala does not have good IDE support apart from Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA.
There is a project called Ensime, but from my own experience it cannot be seriously considered for development.