# Having trouble installing Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, installation

I have a new computer (Windows 10, 64bit) and I can't install Eclipse.
I downloaded a file called **"eclipse-inst-win64.exe"** and a file called **"jdk-12.0.1_windows-x64_bin"**. When I try to open or run as and administrator the Eclipse, I recieve the following message:

"A Java Runtime Enviorment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse Installer. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations:
C:\Users\USER\Downloads\eclipse-inst-win64\jre\bin\javaw.exe
javaw.exe in your current PATH".

What did I do wrong? What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse - no Java (JRE) / (JDK) ... no virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you have to install jdk FIRST. Make sure to set your JAVA_HOME system environment variable to the folder where you installt jdk-12.0.1 and add the bin folder of the jdk to the PATH environment variable. You can test your installation: open a PowerShell and execute java -version. It should display your installed version. If not, the variables are not set correct.