# How to solve eclipse weblogic plugin jdk version compliance error

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, eclipse-plugin, weblogic

How can you set the java home property to a jdk in the eclipse weblogic server tools plugin - when it prompts that "*Java 8 is required*"?  The jdk I specify *is* java 8.

I'm on Windows 10 - I tried eclipse 2019-03 (4.11.0) and an older eclipse photon(4.8.0): they both have this behavior.  My machine has Weblogic 12.2.1.3.0 on it.

The plugin version on my eclipse 2019-03 is: Oracle WebLogic Server Tools   17.3.0.201903121357

I installed the plugin through the "add new server" wizard dialog - not through the marketplace by pasting a zip or jar.

[image: eclipse weblogic plugin error]

The error prompts in the window after I select my weblogic install.

I'm using the Oracle jdk1.8.0_192.  It's included in my path and JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME environment variables.

My eclipse preferences do show the expected system java runtime:

[image]

I tried deleting my eclipse workspace and deleting the eclipse temp files under user home app data - but it did not fix the error prompt.

The closest post I've seen is here, but still doesn't address the version compliance error.

[Eclipse - no Java (JRE) / (JDK) ... no virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found the solution:

Your weblogic installation needs to include a copy of your JDK.
If your weblogic server is installed to `D:\Oracle\wlserver` then
copy your JDK directory's content (all files and folders from `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211`) to  `D:\Oracle\oracle_common\jdk\`.

On the next screen choose your domain directory, which should be something like: `D:\Oracle\user_projects\domains\base_domain`

This looks like a bug, as if Oracle Weblogic Server Tools did not take the path you provide into account. It always searches the same directory for JDK, which is `oracle_common` in the parent directory of your Weblogic installation.

Comment: I tried moving my jdk to oracle_common\jdk - but it still showed the "Java 8 is required" error prompt.

Comment: You might have more than one WebLogic installations on your computer, you need to find the appropriate one. If you are using a standalone server, then it might be installed to a different folder.

Comment: Set your jdk path to <ORACLE_HOME>/common/jdk and all will be good.