# Point eclipse IDE to use another JRE / JDK other than one specified in JAVA_HOME

Tags: eclipse, java

I am having two JRE / SDK in my development environment, however it was necessary in my situation to set JAVA_HOME to 1.4.2, this is causing my eclipse IDE to stop running as it required 1.6 and above.

May i know how i can modify eclipse ini or environment home to use my other 1.6 installation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run eclipse without running JRE install?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789792/how-to-run-eclipse-without-running-jre-install)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789792/how-to-run-eclipse-without-running-jre-install

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please try the eclipse.ini entry above the varargs (the following two lines *must* be two lines in the `eclipse.ini` file)

```
-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.5\bin\javaw.exe
```

[Find the JVM](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F)

Comment: Also to add that this needs to be above the varargs parameter. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the path needs to be on a separate line, eclipse.ini is rather particular about its format.

Comment: You must use back slash, and put it a line after -vm, and then -vmargs . Like that
-vm 
C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs

Answer (score 6):

Right click the project in Package Explorer -> Configure Build Path

[image: Right click the project in Package Explorer -> Configure Build Path]

Add Library -> JRE System Library

[image: Add Library -> JRE System Library]

Set JRE system library to JDK

[image: Set JRE system library to JDK]

Verify JDK is the reference library

[image: Verify JDK is the reference library]

Answer (score 5):

From the menu in the top.. Proceed as follows--

Project-->Properties--> Java Build Path--> Libraries--> JRE System Library.

Now click Edit . Select Alternate JRE. Click Installed JRE. Provide path to your other JDK. Then FINISH.

That's it.