# Is it necessary to modify PATH, CLASSPATH, and JAVA_HOME in order to use Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, java-home, eclipse-classpath

Is it necessary to modify `PATH`, `CLASSPATH`, and `JAVA_HOME` in order to use `Eclipse`?
When writing some code in Eclipse, does one need to change the PATH to add `jdk/bin` path in Windows environment variables? Does it work if one doesn't set `PATH` when only developing in `Eclipse`? Also, are setting `CLASSPATH` and `JAVA_HOME` variables likewise needed?

If so, why would making these changes be necessary if one only develops java in only Eclipse?

Comment: 1. No. 2. No. 3. Only in Eclipse. Window-> Preferences...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Point eclipse IDE to use another JRE / JDK other than one specified in JAVA\_HOME](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881622/point-eclipse-ide-to-use-another-jre-jdk-other-than-one-specified-in-java-home)

Answer (score 2):

No! You should add the path of installed jdk:

```
Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Add
```