# How do i get an 32 bit eclipse that support jvm 1.6.0?

Tags: eclipse, jvm

How do i get an 32 bit eclipse that support jvm 1.6.0?

I installed the newest copy of eclipse and got the following error:
Version 1.6.0 of the JVM is not suitable for thsi product. Version: 1.7 or greater is required.

Comment: Use Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler) - http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Kepler/SR2

Comment: Even if you cannot install a newer JDK on the system, you can still add a JRE to the unzipped Eclipse distribution.   See http://stackoverflow.com/a/872052/53897 for (a bit aged) instructions (I have not tested this)